# Not able to create new app in itunes connect

Tags: app-store-connect, provisioning-profile

I am assigned as developer admin but I am not able to add 
a new app in iTunes connect. When I click on the New app it shows:

> "You have no eligible Bundle IDs for iOS app"

Here is the screen shot: [link here](http://prntscr.com/fxmiwk).

When I click on the Register One here, it opens my Apple
developer account where there is no option for creating a certificate. My Apple id is not paid one. I don't know where to add 
certificate as there is nowhere mentioning certificate. Here is the screen shot: [link](http://prntscr.com/fxmnhr).

Comment: I think, First you need a valid paid developer account.

Comment: You should have a apple developer membership to create certificate and provisioning profile.

Comment: Is this a team account that you have been granted the admin iTunes Connect role on?  Or is this a single iTunes connect account that you created (which by default gives you admin role)?

Comment: no its s team account

Comment: @wottle Hey, My client add me as team admin in his itune account. He is not ready to give his credential. So I want to publish the app to his account through my apple developer ID(not paid membership). How to proceed next for creating certificate?

Comment: You need to have your client add you as an admin of their **developer account** not the iTunes connect account. That will allow you to generate certain and profiles. If they don't want to do that, they will need to generate the cert and profile, and provide you the cert, profile, and the private key associated with the cert. that will allow you to generate a binary. I would highly recommend them adding you as a team member, though.

Answer (score 0):

In order to create a new app in the iTunes Connect, you need to have eligible Bundle ID. You can register a new bundle ID in the developer center for the new app, in the "Certificates, identifiers and profile" section. Once you have done this log off and log back in to iTunes connect and click the '+' button you will be presented with the screen with the new bundle id appearing in the dropdown.

Comment: But in the second screenshot, There is no Paid Apple dev account

Comment: My apologies. I missed the second screenshot. As rightly pointed out, you need a developer account which lets you create certificate and bundle ID. With an active developer license, your portal will look something like this: https://prnt.sc/fxmxxr

Comment: being team admin can I create provisioning profile ? am I should be apple membership?

Comment: I am afraid you can't. The admin should be able to sort this out for you.

Comment: @Shakti yes, for sure you can create certificates if you are the admin. I have done this thing.

Comment: @AnuragSharma Only if it is a paid developer account or an admin on a paid developer account. Also, don't confuse being an iTunesConnect admin with being an Apple Developer account admin.  Two very different things.  In order to create a certificate / profile, you need to be an Apple Developer account admin.  It seems that the OP is an iTunes Connect admin, but not necessarily a developer account admin.  I actually just tried something and will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: @wottle, Of course, it will work only with the paid Apple Dev account. And yes, I know iTunes connect needs a separate invite, But if the owner made a team member/user admin and invited in the iTunes as well then surely user has the access to edit/delete/generate Developer Certificates.

Comment: @AnuragSharma Yes, but it is clear from the second screenshot that the OP is not a developer account admin, or he would be able to create a cert / profile.  Your answer and comments don't tell the OP that they need to become a developer account admin. Neither do you explain to them that they seem to only be an iTunes Connect admin, and they cannot do what is necessary (what you are saying in your answer) without becoming one, or signing up for an individual paid developer account (if this is not a team situation).

Comment: @wottle I didn't give any answer to this OP. :) You should check before!

Comment: @AnuragSharma, Sorry, I mistook you for the answer author. However, your comments to this response claim "yes, for sure you can create certificates if you are the admin. I have done this thing."  - which is not true if you are only the iTunes Connect admin. I just want to make sure others who need this information get accurate information.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create provisioning profiles or certificates through the site on a free developer account.  The free developer account is meant to start trying iOS / MacOS development, and allows you, through Xcode only, to run on devices.  When you do this, Xcode will create a certificate and a 7-day profile to allow the developed app to run on the device for 7 days.

If you want to create full development profiles (last 1 year) / certs, or distribution profiles / certs, you will need to sign up for a paid developer account.

If you are a member of a team account, you could see if any other team members has at least and Admin role on the Developer account has a paid account (Note: there are separate roles for the Apple Developer Account than iTunes Connect). If so, that developer could create the bundle ID / profile / certificates.

**Edit**: 
So I just tried setting up a free developer account as an Apple Developer Account admin, and I was able to create profiles and certificates.  As long as you are an admin on a paid Apple Developer account, simply have your free developer account added as an admin on the paid account's team, and you should be good.  Go to the [Apple Developer site](https://developer.apple.com/account/#/people/) to set up team membership (must do this from the paid account).

Comment: But  i have a free developer  admin account but  i can't add certificate .then what i need to do ?is there any way to create a certificate without creating paid developer account

Comment: Yes, you would just need to be a team member of a paid account. It sounds like you are working for a client.  They have given you access as a role on their iTunes Connect account, now you just need to have them add you to the developer account.

Answer (score 0):

***An ItunesConnect Information can only be added by the AGENT Login not the person with ADMIN/TEAM MEMBER privilege given.***

The Admin can only create and organise developer.apple.com/member centre portal. Not the iTunesConnect that needs to register the app first then all the rest story follows.

Answer (score 0):

**[Update]:** So after trying every logical thing despite of having a valid bundle id, I created a new bundle id and that was the trick, doing that I could then create a new app and begin my upload process. I am not really sure why was this needed to do in the first place as I already had a valid bundle id, maybe i am missing a point here.

**[Summary of what i faced]** I got this issue today (October 2018) when i deleted my app as i messed up few details, when i again tried to add the app by clicking the + button in the MyApp section I could see this issue happening with the same screen as attached by the OP.

I have a valid bundle id and i am the admin of the portal with full access, now i even logged out and logged in back and still the same issue, **I am waiting from past 2 hours for iTunes connect to identify my existing bundle id but it won't and what's surprising is that I just have one bundle id not even a wild card**, I am not really sure if apple wants us to create a new bundle id despite of having a valid one in the portal (this would stink) or wait some more before they complete their background magic.